# Failed to extract secret from Hashicorp vault production mode - EthSigner - Hashicorp Vault

Tags: hyperledger, besu

Working in hashicorp vault dev mode everything works fine but when I use a hashicor vault in production mode I am not able to connect ethsigner. However, i have been checkin if I can extract the secret from the vault using the api:

```
curl     -H "X-Vault-Token: <token>"     -X GET     http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/secret/data/ethsignerSigningKey
{"request_id":"ba39f319-2f2c-0b46-61e4-7d6042334557","lease_id":"","renewable":false,"lease_duration":2764800,"data":{"value":"b0057716d5917badaf911b193b12b910811c1497b5bada8d7711f758981c3773"},"wrap_info":null,"warnings":null,"auth":null}
```

or using the kv instruction:

```
./vault kv get secret/ethsignerSigningKey
==== Data ====
Key      Value
---      -----
value    b0057716d5917badaf911b193b12b910811c1497b5bada8d7711f758981c3773
```

I get the following error in ethsigner:

```
./ethsigner-0.6.1-SNAPSHOT/bin/ethsigner --chain-id=2018 --logging=ALL --downstream-http-host=localhost --downstream-http-port=8545 --http-listen-port=8549 --http-listen-host=0.0.0.0 hashicorp-signer --host=127.0.0.1 --port=8200 --auth-file=authFile --tls-enabled=false
Setting logging level to ALL
2020-06-28 07:52:34.833+00:00 | main | DEBUG | SignerSubCommand | Configuration = HashicorpSubCommand{serverHost=127.0.0.1, serverPort=8200, authFilePath=authFile, timeout=10000, signingKeyPath=/secret/data/ethsignerSigningKey, tlsEnabled=false, tlsKnownServerFile=null}
2020-06-28 07:52:34.878+00:00 | main | INFO  | SignerSubCommand | Version = ethsigner/v0.6.1-dev-1b6082f1/linux-x86_64/-ubuntu-openjdk64bitservervm-java-11
2020-06-28 07:52:34.936+00:00 | main | DEBUG | InternalLoggerFactory | Using SLF4J as the default logging framework
2020-06-28 07:52:34.940+00:00 | main | DEBUG | ResourceLeakDetector | -Dio.netty.leakDetection.level: simple
2020-06-28 07:52:34.940+00:00 | main | DEBUG | ResourceLeakDetector | -Dio.netty.leakDetection.targetRecords: 4
2020-06-28 07:52:34.951+00:00 | main | DEBUG | InternalThreadLocalMap | -Dio.netty.threadLocalMap.stringBuilder.initialSize: 1024
2020-06-28 07:52:34.951+00:00 | main | DEBUG | InternalThreadLocalMap | -Dio.netty.threadLocalMap.stringBuilder.maxSize: 4096
2020-06-28 07:52:34.962+00:00 | main | DEBUG | MultithreadEventLoopGroup | -Dio.netty.eventLoopThreads: 4
2020-06-28 07:52:34.986+00:00 | main | DEBUG | NioEventLoop | -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization: false
2020-06-28 07:52:34.986+00:00 | main | DEBUG | NioEventLoop | -Dio.netty.selectorAutoRebuildThreshold: 512
2020-06-28 07:52:35.001+00:00 | main | DEBUG | PlatformDependent0 | -Dio.netty.noUnsafe: false
2020-06-28 07:52:35.001+00:00 | main | DEBUG | PlatformDependent0 | Java version: 11
2020-06-28 07:52:35.003+00:00 | main | DEBUG | PlatformDependent0 | sun.misc.Unsafe.theUnsafe: available
2020-06-28 07:52:35.003+00:00 | main | DEBUG | PlatformDependent0 | sun.misc.Unsafe.copyMemory: available
2020-06-28 07:52:35.004+00:00 | main | DEBUG | PlatformDependent0 | java.nio.Buffer.address: available
2020-06-28 07:52:35.004+00:00 | main | DEBUG | PlatformDependent0 | direct buffer constructor: unavailable
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Reflective setAccessible(true) disabled
    at io.netty.util.internal.ReflectionUtil.trySetAccessible(ReflectionUtil.java:31) ~[netty-common-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0$4.run(PlatformDependent0.java:224) ~[netty-common-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0.<clinit>(PlatformDependent0.java:218) [netty-common-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.isAndroid(PlatformDependent.java:272) [netty-common-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.<clinit>(PlatformDependent.java:92) [netty-common-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.newTaskQueue0(NioEventLoop.java:284) [netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.newTaskQueue(NioEventLoop.java:155) [netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.<init>(NioEventLoop.java:137) [netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:138) [netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:37) [netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:84) [netty-common-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:58) [netty-common-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:47) [netty-common-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventLoopGroup.java:59) [netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:78) [netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:73) [netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:60) [netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.transport.Transport.eventLoopGroup(Transport.java:148) [vertx-core-3.8.2.jar:3.8.2]
    at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl.<init>(VertxImpl.java:143) [vertx-core-3.8.2.jar:3.8.2]
    at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl.vertx(VertxImpl.java:92) [vertx-core-3.8.2.jar:3.8.2]
    at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxFactoryImpl.vertx(VertxFactoryImpl.java:40) [vertx-core-3.8.2.jar:3.8.2]
    at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxFactoryImpl.vertx(VertxFactoryImpl.java:32) [vertx-core-3.8.2.jar:3.8.2]
    at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxFactoryImpl.vertx(VertxFactoryImpl.java:27) [vertx-core-3.8.2.jar:3.8.2]
    at io.vertx.core.Vertx.vertx(Vertx.java:75) [vertx-core-3.8.2.jar:3.8.2]
    at tech.pegasys.ethsigner.signer.hashicorp.HashicorpSubCommand.createSigner(HashicorpSubCommand.java:126) [ethsigner-signer-hashicorp-0.6.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.6.1-dev-1b6082f1]
    at tech.pegasys.ethsigner.signer.hashicorp.HashicorpSubCommand.createSignerFactory(HashicorpSubCommand.java:150) [ethsigner-signer-hashicorp-0.6.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.6.1-dev-1b6082f1]
    at tech.pegasys.ethsigner.SignerSubCommand.run(SignerSubCommand.java:53) [ethsigner-commandline-0.6.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.6.1-dev-1b6082f1]
    at picocli.CommandLine.executeUserObject(CommandLine.java:1769) [picocli-4.2.0.jar:4.2.0]
    at picocli.CommandLine.access$900(CommandLine.java:145) [picocli-4.2.0.jar:4.2.0]
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.executeUserObjectOfLastSubcommandWithSameParent(CommandLine.java:2150) [picocli-4.2.0.jar:4.2.0]
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2144) [picocli-4.2.0.jar:4.2.0]
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2108) [picocli-4.2.0.jar:4.2.0]
    at picocli.CommandLine$AbstractParseResultHandler.execute(CommandLine.java:1975) [picocli-4.2.0.jar:4.2.0]
    at picocli.CommandLine.execute(CommandLine.java:1904) [picocli-4.2.0.jar:4.2.0]
    at tech.pegasys.ethsigner.CommandlineParser.parseCommandLine(CommandlineParser.java:69) [ethsigner-commandline-0.6.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.6.1-dev-1b6082f1]
    at tech.pegasys.ethsigner.EthSignerApp.main(EthSignerApp.java:40) [ethsigner-0.6.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.6.1-dev-1b6082f1]
2020-06-28 07:52:35.016+00:00 | main | DEBUG | PlatformDependent0 | java.nio.Bits.unaligned: available, true
2020-06-28 07:52:35.018+00:00 | main | DEBUG | PlatformDependent0 | jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.allocateUninitializedArray(int): unavailable
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0$6 cannot access class jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export jdk.internal.misc to unnamed module @2bb7bd00
    at jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.newIllegalAccessException(Reflection.java:361) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:591) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:558) ~[?:?]
    at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0$6.run(PlatformDependent0.java:334) ~[netty-common-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0.<clinit>(PlatformDependent0.java:325) [netty-common-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.isAndroid(PlatformDependent.java:272) [netty-common-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.<clinit>(PlatformDependent.java:92) [netty-common-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.newTaskQueue0(NioEventLoop.java:284) [netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.newTaskQueue(NioEventLoop.java:155) [netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.<init>(NioEventLoop.java:137) [netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:138) [netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:37) [netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:84) [netty-common-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:58) [netty-common-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:47) [netty-common-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventLoopGroup.java:59) [netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:78) [netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:73) [netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:60) [netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.transport.Transport.eventLoopGroup(Transport.java:148) [vertx-core-3.8.2.jar:3.8.2]
    at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl.<init>(VertxImpl.java:143) [vertx-core-3.8.2.jar:3.8.2]
    at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl.vertx(VertxImpl.java:92) [vertx-core-3.8.2.jar:3.8.2]
    at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxFactoryImpl.vertx(VertxFactoryImpl.java:40) [vertx-core-3.8.2.jar:3.8.2]
    at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxFactoryImpl.vertx(VertxFactoryImpl.java:32) [vertx-core-3.8.2.jar:3.8.2]
    at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxFactoryImpl.vertx(VertxFactoryImpl.java:27) [vertx-core-3.8.2.jar:3.8.2]
    at io.vertx.core.Vertx.vertx(Vertx.java:75) [vertx-core-3.8.2.jar:3.8.2]
    at tech.pegasys.ethsigner.signer.hashicorp.HashicorpSubCommand.createSigner(HashicorpSubCommand.java:126) [ethsigner-signer-hashicorp-0.6.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.6.1-dev-1b6082f1]
    at tech.pegasys.ethsigner.signer.hashicorp.HashicorpSubCommand.createSignerFactory(HashicorpSubCommand.java:150) [ethsigner-signer-hashicorp-0.6.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.6.1-dev-1b6082f1]
    at tech.pegasys.ethsigner.SignerSubCommand.run(SignerSubCommand.java:53) [ethsigner-commandline-0.6.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.6.1-dev-1b6082f1]
    at picocli.CommandLine.executeUserObject(CommandLine.java:1769) [picocli-4.2.0.jar:4.2.0]
    at picocli.CommandLine.access$900(CommandLine.java:145) [picocli-4.2.0.jar:4.2.0]
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.executeUserObjectOfLastSubcommandWithSameParent(CommandLine.java:2150) [picocli-4.2.0.jar:4.2.0]
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2144) [picocli-4.2.0.jar:4.2.0]
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2108) [picocli-4.2.0.jar:4.2.0]
    at picocli.CommandLine$AbstractParseResultHandler.execute(CommandLine.java:1975) [picocli-4.2.0.jar:4.2.0]
    at picocli.CommandLine.execute(CommandLine.java:1904) [picocli-4.2.0.jar:4.2.0]
    at tech.pegasys.ethsigner.CommandlineParser.parseCommandLine(CommandlineParser.java:69) [ethsigner-commandline-0.6.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.6.1-dev-1b6082f1]
    at tech.pegasys.ethsigner.EthSignerApp.main(EthSignerApp.java:40) [ethsigner-0.6.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.6.1-dev-1b6082f1]
2020-06-28 07:52:35.020+00:00 | main | DEBUG | PlatformDependent0 | java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(long, int): unavailable
2020-06-28 07:52:35.020+00:00 | main | DEBUG | PlatformDependent | sun.misc.Unsafe: available
2020-06-28 07:52:35.021+00:00 | main | DEBUG | PlatformDependent | maxDirectMemory: 2090860544 bytes (maybe)
2020-06-28 07:52:35.021+00:00 | main | DEBUG | PlatformDependent | -Dio.netty.tmpdir: /tmp (java.io.tmpdir)
2020-06-28 07:52:35.022+00:00 | main | DEBUG | PlatformDependent | -Dio.netty.bitMode: 64 (sun.arch.data.model)
2020-06-28 07:52:35.023+00:00 | main | DEBUG | PlatformDependent | -Dio.netty.maxDirectMemory: -1 bytes
2020-06-28 07:52:35.023+00:00 | main | DEBUG | PlatformDependent | -Dio.netty.uninitializedArrayAllocationThreshold: -1
2020-06-28 07:52:35.025+00:00 | main | DEBUG | CleanerJava9 | java.nio.ByteBuffer.cleaner(): available
2020-06-28 07:52:35.025+00:00 | main | DEBUG | PlatformDependent | -Dio.netty.noPreferDirect: false
2020-06-28 07:52:35.032+00:00 | main | DEBUG | PlatformDependent | org.jctools-core.MpscChunkedArrayQueue: available
2020-06-28 07:52:35.036+00:00 | main | TRACE | NioEventLoop | instrumented a special java.util.Set into: sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@388ba540
2020-06-28 07:52:35.037+00:00 | main | TRACE | NioEventLoop | instrumented a special java.util.Set into: sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@3d484181
2020-06-28 07:52:35.037+00:00 | main | TRACE | NioEventLoop | instrumented a special java.util.Set into: sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@6111ba37
2020-06-28 07:52:35.037+00:00 | main | TRACE | NioEventLoop | instrumented a special java.util.Set into: sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@7be58f16
2020-06-28 07:52:35.038+00:00 | main | TRACE | NioEventLoop | instrumented a special java.util.Set into: sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@56c9bbd8
2020-06-28 07:52:35.069+00:00 | main | DEBUG | DefaultDnsServerAddressStreamProvider | Default DNS servers: [/127.0.0.53:53] (sun.net.dns.ResolverConfiguration)
2020-06-28 07:52:35.074+00:00 | main | DEBUG | NetUtil | -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack: false
2020-06-28 07:52:35.074+00:00 | main | DEBUG | NetUtil | -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses: false
2020-06-28 07:52:35.075+00:00 | main | DEBUG | NetUtil | Loopback interface: lo (lo, 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo)
2020-06-28 07:52:35.076+00:00 | main | DEBUG | NetUtil | /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn: 128
2020-06-28 07:52:35.261+00:00 | vert.x-eventloop-thread-3 | DEBUG | PooledByteBufAllocator | -Dio.netty.allocator.numHeapArenas: 4
2020-06-28 07:52:35.261+00:00 | vert.x-eventloop-thread-3 | DEBUG | PooledByteBufAllocator | -Dio.netty.allocator.numDirectArenas: 4
2020-06-28 07:52:35.261+00:00 | vert.x-eventloop-thread-3 | DEBUG | PooledByteBufAllocator | -Dio.netty.allocator.pageSize: 8192
2020-06-28 07:52:35.262+00:00 | vert.x-eventloop-thread-3 | DEBUG | PooledByteBufAllocator | -Dio.netty.allocator.maxOrder: 11
2020-06-28 07:52:35.262+00:00 | vert.x-eventloop-thread-3 | DEBUG | PooledByteBufAllocator | -Dio.netty.allocator.chunkSize: 16777216
2020-06-28 07:52:35.262+00:00 | vert.x-eventloop-thread-3 | DEBUG | PooledByteBufAllocator | -Dio.netty.allocator.tinyCacheSize: 512
2020-06-28 07:52:35.262+00:00 | vert.x-eventloop-thread-3 | DEBUG | PooledByteBufAllocator | -Dio.netty.allocator.smallCacheSize: 256
2020-06-28 07:52:35.262+00:00 | vert.x-eventloop-thread-3 | DEBUG | PooledByteBufAllocator | -Dio.netty.allocator.normalCacheSize: 64
2020-06-28 07:52:35.263+00:00 | vert.x-eventloop-thread-3 | DEBUG | PooledByteBufAllocator | -Dio.netty.allocator.maxCachedBufferCapacity: 32768
2020-06-28 07:52:35.263+00:00 | vert.x-eventloop-thread-3 | DEBUG | PooledByteBufAllocator | -Dio.netty.allocator.cacheTrimInterval: 8192
2020-06-28 07:52:35.263+00:00 | vert.x-eventloop-thread-3 | DEBUG | PooledByteBufAllocator | -Dio.netty.allocator.cacheTrimIntervalMillis: 0
2020-06-28 07:52:35.263+00:00 | vert.x-eventloop-thread-3 | DEBUG | PooledByteBufAllocator | -Dio.netty.allocator.useCacheForAllThreads: true
2020-06-28 07:52:35.263+00:00 | vert.x-eventloop-thread-3 | DEBUG | PooledByteBufAllocator | -Dio.netty.allocator.maxCachedByteBuffersPerChunk: 1023
2020-06-28 07:52:35.290+00:00 | vert.x-eventloop-thread-3 | DEBUG | DefaultChannelId | -Dio.netty.processId: 14340 (auto-detected)
2020-06-28 07:52:35.292+00:00 | vert.x-eventloop-thread-3 | DEBUG | DefaultChannelId | -Dio.netty.machineId: 7a:1d:18:ff:fe:59:0d:8b (auto-detected)
2020-06-28 07:52:35.324+00:00 | vert.x-eventloop-thread-3 | DEBUG | ByteBufUtil | -Dio.netty.allocator.type: pooled
2020-06-28 07:52:35.324+00:00 | vert.x-eventloop-thread-3 | DEBUG | ByteBufUtil | -Dio.netty.threadLocalDirectBufferSize: 0
2020-06-28 07:52:35.324+00:00 | vert.x-eventloop-thread-3 | DEBUG | ByteBufUtil | -Dio.netty.maxThreadLocalCharBufferSize: 16384
2020-06-28 07:52:35.416+00:00 | vert.x-eventloop-thread-3 | DEBUG | AbstractByteBuf | -Dio.netty.buffer.checkAccessible: true
2020-06-28 07:52:35.416+00:00 | vert.x-eventloop-thread-3 | DEBUG | AbstractByteBuf | -Dio.netty.buffer.checkBounds: true
2020-06-28 07:52:35.417+00:00 | vert.x-eventloop-thread-3 | DEBUG | ResourceLeakDetectorFactory | Loaded default ResourceLeakDetector: io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector@3830b9fc
2020-06-28 07:52:35.457+00:00 | vert.x-eventloop-thread-3 | DEBUG | Recycler | -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread: 4096
2020-06-28 07:52:35.457+00:00 | vert.x-eventloop-thread-3 | DEBUG | Recycler | -Dio.netty.recycler.maxSharedCapacityFactor: 2
2020-06-28 07:52:35.457+00:00 | vert.x-eventloop-thread-3 | DEBUG | Recycler | -Dio.netty.recycler.linkCapacity: 16
2020-06-28 07:52:35.457+00:00 | vert.x-eventloop-thread-3 | DEBUG | Recycler | -Dio.netty.recycler.ratio: 8
Failed to construct a signer from supplied arguments.
Cause: Failed to extract secret from Hashicorp vault.
```

I have also tried with the options:

```
--signing-key-path=/v1/secret/data/ethsignerSigningKey
--signing-key-path=/v1/secret/ethsignerSigningKey
```

but i get the same error.

I am using v0.6.1 but i have also tried v0.5.1 (where the error was "Failed to construct a signer from supplied arguments.
Cause: Invalid response returned from Hashicorp Vault") and the latest docker build.

What could be the problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are using v1 secret engine. dev mode by default uses v2 secret engine and EthSigner also expects v2 secret engine. In production mode, you have to explicitly set v2 when creating it. See https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/kv/kv-v2 for more details. It also points to this tutorial which provides exact steps to enable it. https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vault/versioned-kv

(Posting answer for anyone who ends up here searching on Google.)